# Want to stick element just below fold, jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [sbond's StickToTop jQuery plugin](https://github.com/sdbondi/JQuery-StickToTop) and it isn't working as intended.

The page I am creating has multiple screens that have a `height: 100%;`, meaning that they are the exact height of the browser window.

I have a logo in an  tag just below the fold in the second section. As soon as the user scrolls past the point it would normally go off the top, I want it to stick.

Here's my code;

```
<div id="secondbox">
    <img src="img/logo.png" id="logo">
</div>
```

---

```
var $height = $(window).height();
var $logo = $("img#logo");
$logo.stickToTop();
$logo.stickToTop({ offset: {top: $height}});
```

---

```
img#logo {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 50px 50px;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can give guys!